# Calling and executing function on a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

Let's say, that I have a program code like this:

```
    #include <iostream>  
    #include <Windows.h>

    #include <tbb/tbb.h>


    void SomeFunction()
    {
            // do something
    }        

    void MyThread(int arg)
    {
        std::cout << "This is a thread function\n" << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            arg++;
            Sleep(1);
        }

            SomeFunction();
    }

    int main ()
    {
        tbb::tbb_thread pMyThread = tbb::tbb_thread(MyThread, 3);

        pMyThread.join();

        return 0;
    }
```

From the above  we can see that main() is calling MyThread() on a different thread pMyThread. And MyThread() is calling SomeFunction(). Now, will SomeFunction() (or any other function which is called by MyThread()) be executed on pMyThread too? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, SomeFunction() is executed from the 2nd thread (the one of MyThread()).

Comment: Yes. A thread is a thread of execution. (In fact, if you look at the code, you can see the function is called the "start_routine". It specifies where the thread starts execution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any function call issued from a thread's main function will exist on that thread's private stack.